# Required client entitlement is missing in WKWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, webkit, wkwebview

```
WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
    WKUserContentController *contentController = [[WKUserContentController alloc] init];
    [contentController addScriptMessageHandler:self name:@"slideChanged"];
    [contentController addScriptMessageHandler:self name:@"quizAnswer"];
    [contentController addScriptMessageHandler:self name:@"openPDF"];
    [contentController addScriptMessageHandler:self name:@"openPDFAtPage"];
    configuration.userContentController = contentController;
    configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true;
    configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true;
    configuration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = @[];
```

On line with mediaTypeRequiringUserActionForPlayback I have yellow warning:
**Incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'WKAudiovisualMediaTypes' (aka 'enum WKAudiovisualMediaTypes') from 'NSArray *'*** but I need empty array for autoplay and it's working fine.

and

`[ProcessSuspension] 0x108b78060 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS MediaPlayback assertion 'WebKit Media Playback' for process with PID 52502, error: Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=3 "Required client entitlement is missing" UserInfo={RBSAssertionAttribute=<RBSDomainAttribute| domain:"com.apple.webkit" name:"MediaPlayback" sourceEnvironment:"(null)">,`

What does it mean?

Comment: Simply assign `WKAudiovisualMediaTypeNone` instead of empty `NSArray` `@[]`

Comment: I am also facing same problem . Please post here if you find any solution